# Do collectives get to see my email?

Tags: support, etiquette, privacy, collectives

I noticed in the [Privacy Notice for Collectives™](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy/collectives)

> **WHO IS THE CONTROLLER?**
>
> (...) In addition to this privacy notice, you should review privacy notices of the participating organizations with Collectives pages on Stack Overflow. We and the organization with a Collective may be joint controllers in relation to some activities.

If I join a collective, do the organizations who participate in collectives get my email associated with my account?

Comment: [The notice of the change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370216/179419) is on MSE... I don't see why this _needs_ to be moved site.

Comment: I feel like a useful thing to wonder is "what are the activities where Stack Exchange/Overflow would be joint controllers'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can confirm: your email address is not shared with the Collective client.

Answer (score 19):

The [Joint Controller Agreement](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/Legal/Joint%20Controller%20Agreement%202021.09.22.docx.pdf) linked in that privacy notice between Stack Exchange and Collective owners claims to document all data sharing between collective owners and Stack Exchange on page 8. According to that document, the only private information that is shared is user IDs, so no (assuming that document is correct).